# Group data series into variable width windows based on first event

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have computational task which can be reduced to the follow problem:

I have a large set of pairs of integers (*key*, *val*) which I want to group into windows. The first window starts with the first pair *p* ordered by *key* attribute and spans all the pairs where *p[i].key* belongs to *[p[0].key; p[0].key + N)*, with some arbitrary integer N, positive and common to all windows.

The next window starts with the first pair ordered by *key* not included in the previous windows and again spans all the pairs from its *key* to *key + N*, and so on for the following windows.

The last step is to sum second attribute for each window and display it together with the first key of the window.

For example, given list of records with values:

| key | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 7 | 1 |
| 10 | 3 |
| 13 | 5 |

and N=3, the windows would be:

- {(1,3),(2,7)},
- {(5,1),(6,4),(7,1)},
- {(10,3)}
- {(13,5)}

The final result:

| key | sum_of_values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 10 | 3 |
| 13 | 5 |

This is easy to program with a standard programming language but I have no clue how to solve this with SQL.

Comment: Tag the rdbms you want to use (sql server, mysql, oracle, etc). Also, what happens to the set of keys `1,2,3,4`? Do they make one group `1,2,3,4` or `1,2,3` and `4`?

Comment: @SalmanA, it's been already tagged with clickhouse, but of course a generic solution is welcome. With N=3, 1,2,3,4 should group as {1,2,3} and {4}. The first group starts from 1 and contains the range [1; 4) which does not contains 4, and hence it is grouped separately.

Comment: So the question should state: _from key to key + (N-1)_

Comment: Even if it can be solved with CH (and I think it's doable with Arrays) it will be useless, it's not MPP task, you cannot share computation among threads and shards, it can be computed in a single thread only.

Comment: @DennyCrane, in order to make it more intelligible I simplified the problem a bit. The real  one includes many users each having separate (key, val) pairs. So each user can be processed separately. Any hints on the array solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: If clickhouse doesn't support the `RECURSIVE` keyword, just remove that keyword from the expression.

Clickhouse seems to use non-standard syntax for the `WITH clause`.  The below uses standard SQL.  Adjust as needed.

Sorry. clickhouse may not support this approach.  If not, we would need to find another method of walking through the data.

**Standard SQL:**
There are a few ways.  Here's one approach.  First assign row numbers to allow recursively stepping through the rows.  We could use `LEAD` as well.

Assign a group (key value) to each row based on the current `key` and the last `group/key value` and whether they are within some distance `(N = 3, in this case)`.

The last step is to just `SUM` these values per group `start_key` and to use the `start_key` value as the starting `key` in each group.

```
WITH RECURSIVE nrows (xkey, val, n) AS (
        SELECT xkey, val, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY xkey) FROM test
     )
   , cte (xkey, val, n, start_key) AS (
        SELECT xkey, val, n, xkey FROM nrows WHERE n = 1
         UNION ALL
        SELECT t1.xkey, t1.val, t1.n
             , CASE WHEN t1.xkey <= t2.start_key + (3-1) THEN t2.start_key ELSE t1.xkey END
          FROM nrows AS t1
          JOIN cte   AS t2
            ON t2.n = t1.n-1
     )
SELECT start_key
     , SUM(val) AS sum_values
  FROM cte
 GROUP BY start_key
 ORDER BY start_key
;
```

Result:

```
+-----------+------------+
| start_key | sum_values |
+-----------+------------+
|         1 |         10 |
|         5 |          6 |
|        10 |          3 |
|        13 |          5 |
+-----------+------------+
```

Comment: I wish I could mark that as a solution, but unfortunately clickhouse does not support recursive CTEs. But thanks, I learned some new things from your answer.